# How does Func.realize in Halide works?

Tags: halide

I can understand the explanation in [tutorial 6](https://halide-lang.org/tutorials/tutorial_lesson_06_realizing_over_shifted_domains.html), which is:

```
// Func gradient("gradient");
// Var x("x"), y("y");
// gradient(x, y) = x + y;
// gradient.realize(8, 8);
//
// This does three things internally:
// 1) Generates code than can evaluate gradient over an arbitrary
// rectangle.
// 2) Allocates a new 8 x 8 image.
// 3) Runs the generated code to evaluate gradient for all x, y
// from (0, 0) to (7, 7) and puts the result into the image.
// 4) Returns the new image as the result of the realize call.
```

However, follow the description, I can't figure it out how such a example works:

```
    Func histogram("hist_serial");
    histogram(i) = 0;
    RDom r(0, input.width(), 0, input.height());
    histogram(input(r.x, r.y) / 32) += 1;

    histogram.vectorize(i, 8);
    histogram.realize(8);
```

What I am confusing is: in the "gradient" example, evaluating gradient for all x, y from (0,0) to (7,7) can give us a result, like gradient(1,1)=1+1=2. But in the second example, evaluating histogram for i from 0 to 7 looks strange to me, as I think that we are trying to calculate the result from back to front. A more natural way is to evaluate the input first, then calculate histogram.

So, how the "realize" in the second example works?

Answer (score 1):

Halide automatically infers all of the values which need to be computed to produce a requested region of output. `realize` just asks the pipeline to compute the requested region of the output `Func`(s). Halide then automatically infers what regions of which earlier `Func`s are required, and recursively evaluates all of the those, up to the inputs, before producing the requested region of output.